# collision detection question

Tags: java, collision-detection

Anyone know why this collision for my enemy doesn't work right? It seems when hit from the side it goes through him instead of bouncing off.

```
if(new Rectangle((int) position.x, (int) position.y, size, size).intersects(
new Rectangle((int) enemy.x, (int) enemy.y, enemy.width, enemy.height))){
            if(position.y + size >= enemy.y && position.y + size <= enemy.y + (enemy.height/6))
                velo.y = -velo.y;

            else if(position.y <= enemy.y + enemy.height && position.y >= 
enemy.y + enemy.height - (enemy.height/6))
                velo.y = -velo.y;

            else
                velo.x = -velo.x;

            enemy.hp--;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using the positions to determine whether or not you are coming from the top or not.

consider the following chart:

```
 \    |    /   Assume enemy is at the center.
  \ y | y /    Assume each angle is 45°
   \  |  /     Marked x or y is what you will reverse
 x  \ | /  X
_____\|/_____  An important feature of this is that
     /|\       the Y marked areas will have a slope
 x  / | \  X   through the origin where
   /  |  \          abs(slope) > 1
  / y | y \    And the X will have the remainder
 /    |    \
```

I would use something like this:

```
// split these out just for code clarity hilarity
Rectangle me = new Rectangle((int) position.x, (int) position.y, size, size);
Rectangle them = new Rectangle((int) enemy.x, (int) enemy.y, enemy.width, enemy.height);
if(me.intersects(them)){
    enemy.hp--;
    // find the relative location
    double relx = enemy.x - position.x;
    double rely = enemy.y - position.y;

    // find slope of line between the two of you
    double slope = relx / rely;

    // if abs(slope) > 1, you're in y territory, otherwise, x territory
    if(Math.abs(slope) > 1.0) {
        velo.y = -velo.y;
    }
    else {
        velo.x = -velo.x;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was a awesome post, but it messes up when the ball hits the enemy at a angle. I think I need something that will bounce the ball back from any angle. Still, this is better than what I had, so +1

Comment: gets stuck bouncing inside the enemy.

Answer (score 0):

if your position and the enemy y positions are the same, and you are only moving left or right, then the first if block will be true, and you will do

```
velo.y = -velo.y;
```

but since velo.y is 0, you won't notice it.